# positive level sensitive latch modeling

Tags: verilog, hardware, nonblocking

I am reading someone's verilog code. He has coded latch the following way.

```
input f;
reg fd;

always @(f)
    fd <= f;
```

Since it is a latch, I am a wondering if it +ve level sensitive? i.e., when f is 1, fd will be = f and when f = 0, fd will hold its previous value. Or is this latch level sensitive to both when f = 0 and when f = 1. If this is the case, how can it be made +ve level sensitive?

What would happen, if I change non-blocking statement (<=) to blocking (=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a latch. Latches have at least two input signals (either Set and Reset for a SR Latch, J+K for Toggle Latches, Data and Enable for a D latch).

The circuit you're describing is simply a repeater or buffer. Any time `f` changes (the always block condition), `fd` takes the new value of `f`. This applies regardless of the assignment type (blocking or non-blocking).

If you wanted a level sensitive latch (like a D-Latch), you should use the following:

```
always @(*)
    if (en) fd = f;
```

This circuit will have `fd` follow `f` only if `en` is high. Otherwise, the value of `fd` will remain unchanged.

*(Side note - latches are usually bad for FPGA designs. If you're using an FPGA, you should consider using a register instead).*

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason to buffer f? In the code I am looking at, f is buffered three times like f gets assigned to fd, fd gets assigned to fdd and fdd gets assigned to fddd. Secondly, since there is a non-blocking statement, isn't there going to be a delta delay?

Comment: If it's for an ASIC, you'll sometime buffer to increase the signal drive for something with a high fan out or capacitive load. For FPGA designs, you can have buffers as well, though usually the synthesis tool handles them. As for the NBA, with only one statement, there shouldn't be any synthesized difference. The assignment types refer to how the synthesis or simulation tool processes them, not synthesized circuit.